# how to tweak zoom (respectively Country, city, street...) in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use google maps in my application.

In my application user can type any adress and after it this adress will found on map and marker will set at the place.

I want that if I typed CANADA - I will see aproximately full country

If I typed Toronto - I will see aproximately full city

If I typed street - I want to zoom on street and so on.

I s it possible to realize?

P.S.

I wan to realize like this: https://www.google.ru/maps

1. try to type **USA**
2. try to type **Dallas**
3. try to type **Dallas City Hall**

Comment: Yes.  The geocoder returns a suggested viewport and/or bounds.  What does your existing code look like?  Are you using the geocoder?

Comment: Can you provide example?

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com - [zoom to US state](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2stateSelectList.html) - [zoom to country](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2countrySelectList.html)

Comment: @geocodezip Can you provide answer with explanation and code fragment, please?

Comment: You can't view the source of those examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working:

```
    ....
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
     ...
```

was taken from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete